# How to show foreach table records in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

In each category user can add tables and then records in each table. But how to show everything in category page?

My function in controller:

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $tables = FuelAccountingTable::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
        ->where('category_id', '=', $this->getCategory($slug)['id'])
        ->get();

    foreach ($tables as $table) {
        $records = FuelAccountingRecord::where('table_id', '=', $table->id)
            ->get();
    }

    return view('fuel_accounting.detailed')->with([
        'category' => $this->getCategory($slug),
        'tables' => $tables,
        'records' => $records,
    ]);
}
```

And blade template (in top of page I have @foreach($tables as $table):

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST"
                                      action="{{ route('fuel_accounting_store', $category->slug) }}">
                                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                                    <input type="hidden" name="table_id" value="{{ $table->id }}">

                                    @component('components.table')
                                        @slot('id')
                                            table-{{ $table->id }}
                                        @endslot

                                        @slot('thead')
                                            <tr>
                                                <th width="20%">Pavadinimas</th>
                                                <th width="20%">ISPILTA L.</th>
                                                <th width="20%">ISPILTA KG.</th>
                                                <th width="20%">VERTE EUR.</th>
                                                <th width="20%"></th>
                                            </tr>
                                        @endslot

                                        @slot('tbody')
                                            @foreach($records as $record)
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>{{ $record->name }}</td>
                                                    <td>{{ $record->liters }}</td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            @endforeach
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
                                                <td><input type="number" name="liters"></td>
                                                <td>-</td>
                                                <td>-</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"
                                                            name="saveRecord">Išsaugoti
                                                    </button>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        @endslot
                                    @endcomponent
                                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the relationship between `FuelAccountingTable` and `FuelAccountingRecord` is `hasMany()`. So, [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the data first:

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $category = $this->getCategory($slug);

    $tables = FuelAccountingTable::where('user_id', auth()->id())
        ->where('category_id', $category['id'])
        ->with('fuelAccountingRecords')
        ->get();

    return view('fuel_accounting.detailed', compact('category', 'tables', 'records'));
}
```

Then in the view change this:

```
@foreach($records as $record)
```

To:

```
@foreach($table->fuelAccountingRecords as $record)
```

This will work if the relationship is correctly defined:

```
public function fuelAccountingRecords()
{
    return $this->hasMany(FuelAccountingRecord::class);
}
```

Comment: I already made relationship and now I understand how I need to write function. But if fuel_accounting_tables first column id and fuel_accounting_records has column table_id then how to write or I need to change fuel_accounting_tables id to table_id ?

Comment: @PauliusJasiulis since you're using custom name for foreign key column, you need to define it in the relationship, for example: `$this->hasMany(FuelAccountingRecord::class, 'table_id');`